# Send string to another computer

Tags: vb.net, string, tcp

I have a string that I want to send to another computer that uses my software. I would like to send the string directly to the software in the other computer. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

other alternatives are to use tcp or udp broadcasts

If you need to send the string to multiple computers at once you can use a udp broadcast to 255.255.255.255 ; however with udp there is no confirmation of receipt.

Lots of examples are available if you search for them, here is one:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1(v=VS.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A standard way of achieving such task is to use Sockets. There are plenty of examples over the internet depending on the language and environment you are using.

The following link might be useful to you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx